# 7.2 Umbraco forms - How to

Tags: c#, forms, umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco-contour

Just trying out the new form feature in 7.2.

I have created a form worked out how to get it to render in a template, and I can submit the form.

However, submit the form it tries to post to a controller that does not exist - App Crashes.

When I go back in to the back end of Umbraco I can see the entry I just made.

Three Questions

1. When I created the form I selected a thank you page, why is the user not being re-directed, how can I make it stop crashing?
2. How do I make the entries go in to a custom SQL table, I can put in all the connectionstring information in the umbraco back office, but how do I associate the datastore with the form and how will umbraco know what feild in the database should map to what feild in the form?
3. Is it possible to make very simple forms that saves in to a db with out any real .net back end coding, can it be done through the UI?

Comment: Why has this been voted down 3 times? Why...... stack over people Why?

Comment: It's being voted as off-topic (click the "close (3)" link and then the "off-topic because..."  to see the reasons. You'd be better off asking this at http://our.umbraco.org

Answer (score 0):

1) No idea, I would need to see at the error message that you get. You should probably include that in the post, it makes it easier for people to help you.

2) Assuming you mean you've set up the Data Source in Umbraco Forms, you should be able to create the form using the UI. Instructions can be found here [on the documentation site](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/umbraco-pro/contour/documentation/Editor/Creating-Forms-Based-on-Datasources/) that should automatically map everything for you. Alternatively, create a custom workflow and dump everything into your database there (again, Workflows are covered in the documentation).

3) You either have to use Umbraco Forms, which save all the form data for you anyway, and allows you to create forms with no .net coding whatsoever, or you have to code them from scratch.

You don't really explain why you're trying to save the form to a database table, Umbraco Forms saves all the records fort you anyway, so is the a separate database?